# Copying BMP Header

Tags: c, file, io, bitmap

I am trying to copy the header of one BMP file into another, checking that the file is 24-bit uncompressed. This is resulting in an error (via my if statement).

This is the structs used to hold the header data

```
typedef uint8_t   BYTE;
typedef uint16_t  WORD;
typedef uint32_t  DWORD;
typedef int32_t LONG;

// Hold Bitmap File Header Information
typedef struct
{
    WORD   bfType;          // File Type MUST BE BM
    DWORD  bfSize;          // Bitmap File: Size in Bytes
    WORD   bfReserved1;     // Reserved: MUST BE 0
    WORD   bfReserved2;     // Reserved: MUST BE 0
    DWORD  bfOffBits;       // Offset: Beginning of BITMAPFILEHEADER to Bitmap Bits
} BITMAPFILEHEADER;

// Hold Bitmap Info Header Information
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER {
    DWORD biSize;           // Bytes required by the structure
    LONG  biWidth;          // Specific the width of the bitmap in pixels
    LONG  biHeight;         // Height of bitmap in pixels
    WORD  biPlanes;         // Set number of planes to target device. HAS to be set to 1
    WORD  biBitCount;       // Number of bits per pixel || Uncompressed Formats Average Number Of Bits Per Pixel
    DWORD biCompression;    // Type of compression
    DWORD biSizeImage;      // Size of image in bytes
    LONG  biXPelsPerMeter;  // Horizitonal resolution in pixels per meter 
    LONG  biYPelsPerMeter;  // Vertical resolution in pixels per meter
    DWORD biClrUsed;        // Specifies no. of colour indices in the color table
    DWORD biClrImportant;   // Speifiies no. of colours that are important for displaying bitmap
} BITMAPINFOHEADER, * LPBITMAPINFOHEADER, * PBITMAPINFOHEADER;
```

```
FILE* Original = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (Original == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Couldn't open file\n");
        printf("Check File Name\n\n");
    }

    // Read Header
    BITMAPFILEHEADER BF;
    fread(&BF, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), ONCE, Original);  // Read File Header

    BITMAPINFOHEADER BI;
    fread(&BI, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), ONCE, Original);  // Read Info Header

    // Check File -> 24-Bit Uncompressed
    if (BF.bfType != 0x4D42 || BF.bfOffBits != 54 ||
        BI.biSize != 40 || BI.biBitCount != 24 || BI.biCompression != 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Incorrect File Type\n");
        printf("Check Bitmap Header!\n\n");
        fclose(Original);
    }
```

I have tried printf the struct data and I am even getting the wrong numbers inside of those, such as

> bfType: 19778
> bfOffBits: 8126464
> biSize: 83886080
> biBitCount: 0
> biCompression: -83886080

Comment: The `struct`s have to be packed, and endianness applies too. *Always* check the number of items read by `fread`. What is `ONCE`? Is that supposed to be `1`? It would be better if your reversed the `size` and `count` arguments, and check that the correct number of bytes were read (the expected header size).

Comment: You need to understand how struct members are aligned by your compiler.

Comment: Currently using GCC complier, but as you both said will look into that

Comment: @WeatherVane, Yes ONCE is 1. When you say reverse Size and Count arguments what do you mean by that?

Comment: & would it be best to hardcode each fread, to tell how many bytes have been read

Comment: You can read *x* items size *y*, or *y* items size *x* - it's the same number of bytes. But `fread` returns the number of items read. So one way round, you could have verified that the correct size was read. Always check what `fread` returns and the `1` returned here hides your misconception about the header struct size.